# Почему container podman с postgresql собирается, запускается, но потом сразу останаваливается?

Tags: postgresql, altlinux, podman

Я не пойму почему контейнер не запускается, и не выдаёт никакх ошибок, что я не так сделал ?

Сделал такой Postgresfile

```
 FROM alt:latest     
    RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y locales
    ENV LANG='ru_RU.UTF-8' LANGUAGE='ru_RU:ru' LC_ALL='ru_RU.UTF-8'
    ENV PGDATA /var/lib/pgsql/data
    ENV PG /var/lib/pgsql
    ENV DUMP_DIR="/mnt/data"
    
    COPY --chmod=755 /../apt/* /etc/apt
    
    RUN set -ex;\
        apt-get update; \
        apt-get install -y \
            ca-certificates \
            curl \
            wget \ 
            openssl \          
            curl \
            mc \
            sudo  \
            postgresql15-server \
            postgresql15 \
            postgresql15-contrib &&\
            apt-get clean &&\ 
            rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&\ 
            apt-get autoremove -y;
    
    
    RUN set -eux;\
        if getent group postgres; then \
            groupmod -g 999 postgres; \
        else \
            groupadd -r postgres --gid=999; \
        fi; \
        if getent passwd postgres; then \
           usermod -u 999 -g 999 postgres; \
        else \
           useradd -r -g postgres -G wheel -m --uid=999 --shell=/bin/bash postgres; \
        fi;       
        
    RUN mkdir -p "$PGDATA" && \
        chown -R postgres:postgres "$PGDATA" && \
        chmod 777 "$PGDATA" && \
        mkdir "$DUMP_DIR"; \
        chmod 777 "$DUMP_DIR" && \
        chown postgres:postgres "$DUMP_DIR" &&\
        chown -R postgres:postgres "$PG" ;
    
    VOLUME ["$DUMP_DIR"]
    
    COPY --chmod=777 init_db.sh /init_db.sh
    COPY --chmod=777 init_db_func.sh /init_db_func.sh
    
    ENTRYPOINT ["/init_db.sh"]
```

init_db_func.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


function RunPg(){
    echo "Запуск Сервер БД"
    # Проверим есть ли в data диреткории файлы базы данных , если есть то попытаемся запустить
    if  [[ -f "$PGDATA/PG_VERSION" ]] ; then    
    
        local PgStatus=$(pg_ctl status)

        echo "статус: $PgStatus"
        if [[ "$PgStatus" =~ .*"сервер не работает".*  ]]; then
            
            echo "статус 1: $PgStatus"
            pg_ctl start
            PgStatus=$(pg_ctl status)
            echo "статус 2: $PgStatus"
            
            while ! [[ "$PgStatus" =~ .*"сервер работает".*  ]]; do
                echo "Сервер в процессе запуска: $PgStatus"
                sleep 5;
            done        

            if [[ "$PgStatus" =~ .*"сервер работает".*  ]]; then
                echo "Сервер работает"
                # rm "$DUMP_DIR/initialization.failed"
                # set +ex
                echo "База запущена"

                return 0
            fi
        fi
    else 
        echo "База не инициализирована"    
        return 1
    fi
}


function ConfigPG(){

    if [ -f "$PGDATA/postgresql.conf" ]; then
        local MEMORY=$(awk '/MemTotal/ {printf "%d", $2/1024}' /proc/meminfo)
        local MAX_CONNECTIONS=$((MEMORY/50+3))
        
        if [ -n "$MAX_CONNECTIONS" ]; then
            sed -i "s|^max_connections =.*|max_connections = $MAX_CONNECTIONS|" "$PGDATA/postgresql.conf"
        fi

    
        if grep -q "#log_checkpoints" "$PGDATA/postgresql.conf"; then
            sed -i "s|#log_checkpoints.*|log_checkpoints = off|" "$PGDATA/postgresql.conf"
        fi
        
        if grep -q "#listen_addresses" "$PGDATA/postgresql.conf"; then
            sed -i "s|#listen_addresses.*|listen_addresses = '*' |" "$PGDATA/postgresql.conf"
        fi
        return 0
    fi
    return 0
}

function InitDB(){
   
    local PgStatusInit=$(pg_ctl initdb -o "-E=UTF8")

    if [[ "$PgStatusInit" =~ .*"Success. You can now start the database server using".* ]]; then

        echo "База успешно инициализирована"
        return 0
     else 
        echo "Ошибка инициализации БД $PgStatusInit"   
        return 1
    fi

}

function CheckInitDB(){
    
    psql --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
    SELECT datname FROM pg_database;
    EOSQL
    
    if [[ $? =~ .*"$NEXCLOUD_DB".* ]]; then
        echo "База данных существует"
        # return 0
    else
        echo "База данных не существует"
        return 1
    fi

}

function CreateUser(){  
    
# psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL

    psql --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE DATABASE "$POSTGRES_DB";
        CREATE USER "$NEXTCLOUD_USER" WITH PASSWORD '$POSTGRES_PASSWORD' CREATEDB;
        ALTER DATABASE "$POSTGRES_DB" OWNER TO "$NEXTCLOUD_USER";
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "$POSTGRES_DB" TO "$NEXTCLOUD_USER";
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO "$NEXTCLOUD_USER";
    EOSQL
}
```

init_db.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex
# shellcheck source=./init_db_func.sh
source ./init_db_func.sh

ls "$DUMP_DIR"
echo "$NEXCLOUD_USER"
RunPg

if [[  "$?" == 1 ]]; then
    InitDB
    if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
        ConfigPG
        RunPg
        CreateUser
    fi
fi

pg_ctl status
```

Затем сборка ОК

```
podman build -f Postgresfile -t postgresql:1.0 .

....

Successfully tagged localhost/postgresql:1.0
26106a611daf68533e4f4347a37cb66293074fd6f4cf2165b8b5c00e8c922326
```

И Запуск

```
podman run -it -p5432:5432/tcp  --secret db_passwd,type=env,target=POSTGRES_PASSWORD   --env-file=postgres.env -v /var/postgresql:/var/lib/pgsql/   postgresql:1.0
....

База запущена
pg_ctl: сервер работает (PID: 6)
/usr/bin/postgres
```

но он тут контейнер сразу останавливается

```
$ podman ps
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE       COMMAND     CREATED     STATUS      PORTS       NAMES
```

inspect контейнера

```
podman container inspect priceless_agnesi
[
     {
          "Id": "45eefc35e0e812bf60750d0b480da65194680407e47b1c5951c2ae8ee83c0bc4",
          "Created": "2023-09-15T11:41:40.455988672+03:00",
          "Path": "/init_db.sh",
          "Args": [
               "/init_db.sh"
          ],
          "State": {
               "OciVersion": "1.0.2-dev",
               "Status": "exited",
               "Running": false,
               "Paused": false,
               "Restarting": false,
               "OOMKilled": false,
               "Dead": false,
               "Pid": 0,
               "ExitCode": 0,
               "Error": "",
               "StartedAt": "2023-09-15T11:41:40.701252531+03:00",
               "FinishedAt": "2023-09-15T11:41:41.883216032+03:00",
               "Health": {
                    "Status": "",
                    "FailingStreak": 0,
                    "Log": null
               },
               "CheckpointedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
               "RestoredAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
          },
          "Image": "26106a611daf68533e4f4347a37cb66293074fd6f4cf2165b8b5c00e8c922326",
          "ImageDigest": "sha256:4dea2ca01da99f09f527b8ebb277cdf4c61cd90b33ad35e848e82df221300ac2",
          "ImageName": "localhost/postgresql:1.0",
          "Rootfs": "",
          "Pod": "",
          "ResolvConfPath": "/run/user/504/containers/overlay-containers/45eefc35e0e812bf60750d0b480da65194680407e47b1c5951c2ae8ee83c0bc4/userdata/resolv.conf",
          "HostnamePath": "/run/user/504/containers/overlay-containers/45eefc35e0e812bf60750d0b480da65194680407e47b1c5951c2ae8ee83c0bc4/userdata/hostname",
          "HostsPath": "/run/user/504/containers/overlay-containers/45eefc35e0e812bf60750d0b480da65194680407e47b1c5951c2ae8ee83c0bc4/userdata/hosts",
          "StaticDir": "/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-containers/45eefc35e0e812bf60750d0b480da65194680407e47b1c5951c2ae8ee83c0bc4/userdata",
          "OCIConfigPath": "/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay-containers/45eefc35e0e812bf60750d0b480da65194680407e47b1c5951c2ae8ee83c0bc4/userdata/config.json",
          "OCIRuntime": "crun",
          "ConmonPidFile": "/run/user/504/containers/overlay-containers/45eefc35e0e812bf60750d0b480da65194680407e47b1c5951c2ae8ee83c0bc4/userdata/conmon.pid",
          "PidFile": "/run/user/504/containers/overlay-containers/45eefc35e0e812bf60750d0b480da65194680407e47b1c5951c2ae8ee83c0bc4/userdata/pidfile",
          "Name": "priceless_agnesi",
          "RestartCount": 0,
          "Driver": "overlay",
          "MountLabel": "",
          "ProcessLabel": "",
          "AppArmorProfile": "",
          "EffectiveCaps": null,
          "BoundingCaps": [
               "CAP_CHOWN",
               "CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE",
               "CAP_FOWNER",
               "CAP_FSETID",
               "CAP_KILL",
               "CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE",
               "CAP_SETFCAP",
               "CAP_SETGID",
               "CAP_SETPCAP",
               "CAP_SETUID",
               "CAP_SYS_CHROOT"
          ],
          "ExecIDs": [],
          "GraphDriver": {
               "Name": "overlay",
               "Data": {
                    "LowerDir": "/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/fbac4bbc49503be3376e096371a623307b27a988cc0874df79bf56e2336b3932/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/487dd6d889d0d337246b1502b2af004dd5b020fe5283193ebd7d69073782b81b/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/eea8c50ade4c7d02e9dfbf1df744b5f09cbb172a57daf8de3fc9a7f3da2b4f71/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/94e661d8f14ec3aa84f03b3dbc0d9704894b2369c6b31fc5ef82c5716d907503/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/24924904765e632d513f8160d5422042a604ad38172313f9dd39acd29126ce39/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/a59e2e7cc328e20615c959d55ebbde151d26e19f30c968a1c40a4323f2f7a819/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/08774baa1dfb4e38f4b351264d9b067d48b57158a534c374c0e810c95ca1e821/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/ad0e0fa13f59e285cc510fcb5369252e5cbea1994e1b2d5c7129fb8e54c0a01f/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/d7a8ed2ce846bc03e72093e4f256cfdeda8ca9e0b9de0a97c08d2aa5e24bc0e5/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/a15858a1b68f9564907abda50f227b3dffdd277d9c1a539c71d64677880089fa/diff:/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/9d30b4e6f797b35b9f10865838f4dd7816998e0aaa9281f372e6ecc5b912f901/diff",
                    "UpperDir": "/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/335abf3b1b04268f30f45392e070c797d49c527efeaf7cf54e17b4c4503c9ae0/diff",
                    "WorkDir": "/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/335abf3b1b04268f30f45392e070c797d49c527efeaf7cf54e17b4c4503c9ae0/work"
               }
          },
          "Mounts": [
               {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Name": "55d65d841bf92b816166286545290c76aa3724edc102e67b8746949f741de41c",
                    "Source": "/home/poduser/.local/share/containers/storage/volumes/55d65d841bf92b816166286545290c76aa3724edc102e67b8746949f741de41c/_data",
                    "Destination": "/mnt/data",
                    "Driver": "local",
                    "Mode": "",
                    "Options": [
                         "nodev",
                         "exec",
                         "nosuid",
                         "rbind"
                    ],
                    "RW": true,
                    "Propagation": "rprivate"
               },
               {
                    "Type": "bind",
                    "Source": "/var/postgresql",
                    "Destination": "/var/lib/pgsql/",
                    "Driver": "",
                    "Mode": "",
                    "Options": [
                         "rbind"
                    ],
                    "RW": true,
                    "Propagation": "rprivate"
               }
          ],
          "Dependencies": [],
          "NetworkSettings": {
               "EndpointID": "",
               "Gateway": "",
               "IPAddress": "",
               "IPPrefixLen": 0,
               "IPv6Gateway": "",
               "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
               "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
               "MacAddress": "",
               "Bridge": "",
               "SandboxID": "",
               "HairpinMode": false,
               "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
               "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
               "Ports": {
                    "5432/tcp": [
                         {
                              "HostIp": "",
                              "HostPort": "5432"
                         }
                    ]
               },
               "SandboxKey": ""
          },
          "Namespace": "",
          "IsInfra": false,
          "IsService": false,
          "Config": {
               "Hostname": "45eefc35e0e8",
               "Domainname": "",
               "User": "postgres",
               "AttachStdin": false,
               "AttachStdout": false,
               "AttachStderr": false,
               "Tty": true,
               "OpenStdin": true,
               "StdinOnce": false,
               "Env": [
                    "TERM=xterm",
                    "container=podman",
                    "LANGUAGE=ru_RU:ru",
                    "PG=/var/lib/pgsql",
                    "POSTGRES_USER=postgres",
                    "POSTGRES_PORT=5432",
                    "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                    "LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8",
                    "PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/data",
                    "DUMP_DIR=/mnt/data",
                    "LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8",
                    "NEXTCLOUD_USER=nextuser",
                    "POSTGRES_DB=nextcloud_db",
                    "HOME=/var/lib/pgsql",
                    "HOSTNAME=45eefc35e0e8",
                    "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PaSSw0rd"
               ],
               "Cmd": null,
               "Image": "localhost/postgresql:1.0",
               "Volumes": null,
               "WorkingDir": "/",
               "Entrypoint": "/init_db.sh",
               "OnBuild": null,
               "Labels": {
                    "io.buildah.version": "1.29.0"
               },
               "Annotations": {
                    "io.container.manager": "libpod",
                    "org.opencontainers.image.base.digest": "sha256:5a9bb62d596432d5fa41ef9b135e665b2d3200f32911fcefcb65e7014b74a2c1",
                    "org.opencontainers.image.base.name": "registry.altlinux.org/alt/alt:latest",
                    "org.opencontainers.image.stopSignal": "2"
               },
               "StopSignal": 2,
               "HealthcheckOnFailureAction": "none",
               "CreateCommand": [
                    "podman",
                    "run",
                    "-it",
                    "-p5432:5432/tcp",
                    "--secret",
                    "db_passwd,type=env,target=POSTGRES_PASSWORD",
                    "--env-file=postgres.env",
                    "-v",
                    "/var/postgresql:/var/lib/pgsql/",
                    "postgresql:1.0"
               ],
               "Umask": "0022",
               "Timeout": 0,
               "StopTimeout": 10,
               "Passwd": true,
               "sdNotifyMode": "container"
          },
          "HostConfig": {
               "Binds": [
                    "55d65d841bf92b816166286545290c76aa3724edc102e67b8746949f741de41c:/mnt/data:rprivate,rw,nodev,exec,nosuid,rbind",
                    "/var/postgresql:/var/lib/pgsql/:rw,rprivate,rbind"
               ],
               "CgroupManager": "systemd",
               "CgroupMode": "private",
               "ContainerIDFile": "",
               "LogConfig": {
                    "Type": "journald",
                    "Config": null,
                    "Path": "",
                    "Tag": "",
                    "Size": "0B"
               },
               "NetworkMode": "slirp4netns",
               "PortBindings": {
                    "5432/tcp": [
                         {
                              "HostIp": "",
                              "HostPort": "5432"
                         }
                    ]
               },
               "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Name": "",
                    "MaximumRetryCount": 0
               },
               "AutoRemove": false,
               "VolumeDriver": "",
               "VolumesFrom": null,
               "CapAdd": [],
               "CapDrop": [],
               "Dns": [],
               "DnsOptions": [],
               "DnsSearch": [],
               "ExtraHosts": [],
               "GroupAdd": [],
               "IpcMode": "shareable",
               "Cgroup": "",
               "Cgroups": "default",
               "Links": null,
               "OomScoreAdj": 0,
               "PidMode": "private",
               "Privileged": false,
               "PublishAllPorts": false,
               "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
               "SecurityOpt": [],
               "Tmpfs": {},
               "UTSMode": "private",
               "UsernsMode": "",
               "ShmSize": 65536000,
               "Runtime": "oci",
               "ConsoleSize": [
                    0,
                    0
               ],
               "Isolation": "",
               "CpuShares": 0,
               "Memory": 0,
               "NanoCpus": 0,
               "CgroupParent": "user.slice",
               "BlkioWeight": 0,
               "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
               "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
               "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
               "CpuPeriod": 0,
               "CpuQuota": 0,
               "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
               "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
               "CpusetCpus": "",
               "CpusetMems": "",
               "Devices": [],
               "DiskQuota": 0,
               "KernelMemory": 0,
               "MemoryReservation": 0,
               "MemorySwap": 0,
               "MemorySwappiness": 0,
               "OomKillDisable": false,
               "PidsLimit": 2048,
               "Ulimits": [],
               "CpuCount": 0,
               "CpuPercent": 0,
               "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
               "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
               "CgroupConf": null
          }
     }
]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Сам разобрался, podman контейнеры не работают с процессами которые запущены с отвязкой от терминала или потока вывода stdout, как следствие нужно запускать так чтобы процесс был запущен внутри контейнера не как фоновый....
Подсказку нашёл в /etc/init.d/postgrsql